# Funciones con paso de parámetros por valor y referencia en C

Tags: c

Buenas a todos estoy aprendiendo sobre funciones con paso de parámetros por valor y referencia, estoy haciendo un programa muy sencillo y no entiendo por que me devuelve un resultado incorrecto, necesito vuestra ayuda.
Este es el código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void sumar_elem(int *resultado, int n1, int n2);
void ingresar(int n1, int n2);

void sumar_elem(int *resultado, int n1, int n2) {
*resultado = (n1 + n2);
}

void ingresar(int n1, int n2) {
printf("Ingrese el primer numero: \n");
scanf("%d",&n1);
printf("Ingrese el segundo numero: \n");
scanf("%d",&n2);
}

 int main() {
 int n1;
 int n2;
 int resultado;
 resultado = 0;
 ingresar(n1,n2);
 sumar_elem(&resultado,n1,n2);
 printf("La suma de los elementos: %d = %d + %d\n",resultado,n1,n2);
 return 0;
}
```

la salida del programa una vez ingresado los valores, me devuelve

> la suma de los elementos es: 1 = 0  + 1

Comment: Te recomiendo que pongas un título descriptivo a la pregunta que harás.

Comment: En [tag:c] no existe ell paso por referencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está claro que el problema radica aquí:

```
ingresar(n1,n2);
sumar_elem(&resultado, n1, n2);
```

Y esto se debe, por la forma como estás declarando ambas funciones:

```
void sumar_elem(int *resultado, int n1, int n2);
void ingresar(int n1, int n2);
```

La función `ingresar` tiene dos parámetros, `n1` y `n2`, cuando esa función se llame, le pedirás al usuario que ingrese dos datos, el problema radica que cuando la función termine de ejecutarse, esos valores se pierden y así, sería imposible llamar posteriormente la función `sumar_elem`.

La solución sería declarar las dos funciones de esta forma:

```
void sumar_elem(int *resultado, int* n1, int* n2);
void ingresar(int* n1, int* n2);
```

Entonces, cuando llames la función `ingresar`, estarías pasando la dirección de memoria de la variable (`n1` y `n2`) y de ese modo, no se pierde esa información ingresada por el usuario.

El código completo sería:

```
void sumar_elem(int *resultado, int* n1, int* n2) 
{
   *resultado = *n1 + *n2;
}

void ingresar(int* n1, int* n2) 
{
  printf("Ingrese el primer numero: \n");
  scanf("%d", n1);
  printf("Ingrese el segundo numero: \n");
  scanf("%d", n2);
}

 int main()
 {
    int n1;
    int n2;
    int resultado;
    //Le pasamos la dirección de memoria de n1 y n2.
    ingresar(&n1, &n2);
    //Le pasamos la dirección de memoria de n1 y n2.
    sumar_elem(&resultado, &n1, &n2);
    printf("La suma de los elementos: %d = %d + %d\n", resultado, n1, n2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: En la función **void ingresar(int* n1, int* n2)**,** scanf "%d"** 
  indica que trabajar a con un entero, si bien n1 y n2 son enteros, pero también son **punteros**, por lo que es necesario crear variables auxiliares de tipo int y llamar a estas con scanf "%d", posteriormente igualar los punteros con esos valores.

Comment: @nando El código funciona perfectamente. Las variables auxiliares es de por gusto. Los parámetros n1 y n2 son punteros, es decir, tienen una dirección de memoria (de la variable que pasaste como referencia), esto quiere decir que cuando llames la función scanf, le estarías pasando esa dirección de memoria que tenga guardado el puntero, donde scanf enviará el valor introducido por el usuario hacia esa dirección. Prueba el código y te darás cuenta.

Comment: tienes razón, ese forma es mejor

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el envió de tus referencia y manejo de punteros.

-En el **prototipo de la funciones y en las funciones como tal** te falto los punteros ***n1 y *n2**

-En la función **main**, también debes enviar las referencias **&n1 y &n2** a las funciones **sumar_elem() y ingresar ()**.

-En tu función ingresar(), debes crear dos variables de tipo entero y luego igualar los punteros con los valores de estos. Esto porque **scanf "%d"** trabajara con dato entero y la función está recibiendo  parámetros de tipo *punteros

El código quedaría de este modo.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void sumar_elem(int *resultado, int *n1, int *n2);
void ingresar(int *n1, int *n2);

void sumar_elem(int *resultado, int *n1, int *n2) {
*resultado = (*n1 + *n2);
}

void ingresar(int *n1, int *n2) {
    int N1;
    int N2;
    printf("Ingrese el primer numero: \n");
    scanf("%d",&N1);
    printf("Ingrese el segundo numero: \n");
    scanf("%d",&N2);
    *n1=N1;
    *n2=N2;
}

int main() {
 int n1;
 int n2;
 int resultado;
 resultado = 0;
 ingresar(&n1,&n2);
 sumar_elem(&resultado,&n1,&n2);
 printf("La suma de los elementos:  %d + %d = %d\n",n1,n2,resultado);
 return 0;
}
```

Te invito a revisar la documentación de funciones en [C](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Uso_de_funciones)

Tambien puedes ver el resultado [Aqui](https://onlinegdb.com/Hy4vkBttB)

Comment: Las variables locales N1 y N2 son innecesarios. Básicamente puedes enviar directamente la dirección de memoria que tenga almacenado el puntero a la función scanf.

Comment: Tienes razón, si envías directamente  la dirección de memoria;  pero si envías la referencia como en el código inicial **scanf("%d",&n1)**  dará error.